# How to prevent commit from eclipse when new code reports sonar issues

Tags: git, eclipse, sonarqube, hook

I am struggling with a use case:
I have an eclipse instance connected with Gitlab [on Linux]. I need to prevent code commit when the newly developed lines report any sonar issues.
Eclipse [windows]
Gitlab and Sonarqube [Linux]

I think I need to use pre-commit hook for Sonarqube for above usecase but to configure hook I don't have sonar-scanner got installed on my windows [since sonarqube server is up as container on Linux]

Let me talk about Sonarlint plugin [as an alternative] that can report sonar issues in eclipse. I got more confused after checking lot of references.

According to sources I found that most of the pre-commit hook scripts are implemented in .sh file and eclipse is on windows machine. How can I execute my [sh] hook from eclipse?

I found Cygwin as a solution in some blog that would help to run shell file in eclipse, but most of the sonarqube pre commit hook logics are implemented either by **checking exit code status of sonar-scanner or sonar quality gate status**. If I prefer Sonarlint plugin will my hook script still works?

(Solution) enable sonarqube pre-commit hook in eclipse.
If any of you find solution is inappropriate please provide your suggestions.

I ended up with confusion. I wish someone can help me or share most relevant reference of my usecase.

Though I found many related blogs in SO, I failed in applying them.

Waiting for support.
Thankyou in advance

Comment: AFAICU "SonarLint is an IDE extension that helps you detect and fix quality issues as you write code." and I can't see how it can interfere with (not-existing yet?) pre-commit hook. NB - I know *nothing* about Eclipse and|or Sonarqube

Comment: Yes even I didn't find any pre-commit hooks for Sonarlint. I agree as you said there is no such thing existing [ I guess ] but  I am just trying to explore the possibility of my usecase whether I can create a custom hook of my own  It's just an idea and not sure how well it works

Answer (score 1):

I've heard of this unfortunate anti-pattern a few times.  It's simply not practical to do this.

You should instead design a build and development architecture that only allows direct commits to feature branches.  The feature branch is referenced in a pull request, which when created and added to, will spawn a build of the feature branch, which includes an authoritative SonarQube scan, which can use SonarQube quality gate checking, but you can also add additional quality gate checks into the build process, which uses the SonarQube REST api to get scan information and add more specific domain-specific checks, or simply checks for things that SonarQube doesn't check for.  If the SonarQube quality gate fails, or the domain-specific post-checks fail, the build will fail.  You'll need to configure your pull requests so that if the associated build fails, the pull request cannot be merged to the target branch.

Comment: So with the pre commit hooks there is no scope right!! can I take it as impractical? I can't prevent code commit (with sonar issues) directly in IDE itself rather as you said I need to commit it to feature branch --> sonar analysis --> based on analysis report merge to main branch. I think I can automate the quality check using a ci pipeline